# Visual Studio Code "Git not found"

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code

I have Windows10 with the Ubuntu bash and Visual Studio Code.

Every time I start Visual Studio Code it prompts a warning saying:

> Git not found. Install it or configure it using the 'git.path' setting

I got git actually installed through the bash terminal:

```
# which git
/usr/bin/git
```

How can I instruct Visual Studio Code to use that git installed in the bash terminal?

I have tried through the **git.path** setting but I am not sure how to set the path to something that is relative to the bash terminal.

Comment: You can make that an answer, since the ubuntu installed git will not be found indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Visual Studio Code on Windows, you also need to install Git for Windows. VsCode currently can't access git on the linux subsystems.

Comment: Can´t I alias the git from windows to the one from bash? And then call the git from windows that eventually call the git from bash...

Comment: Doesn't work that way. Looking for a way to get a hook working or something?